# Can I bound from above the following term via a polynomial $p(\frac{1}{\varepsilon},\frac{1}{\delta})$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I want to bound the following term $\frac{8d}{(\delta \varepsilon)^2}\log{(\frac{2d}{(\delta\varepsilon)^2})}+\frac{4d}{(\delta\varepsilon)^2}\log{(2 \frac{e}{d})}<p(\frac{1}{\varepsilon},\frac{1}{\delta})$ where $p(x,y)$ is some polynomial and $d \in \mathbb N, \; e := \exp(1)$ and further the arguments $\delta,\varepsilon \in (0,1]$.

I am having a difficult time finding some polynomial.

My attempt, set $\log{(2 \frac{e}{d})}:=a$ and further since $1\geq\delta, \varepsilon> 0$, we obtain that $\log{(\frac{2d}{(\delta\varepsilon)^2}})\leq 1+\frac{1}{(\delta\varepsilon)^2}$

$\frac{8d}{(\delta \varepsilon)^2}\log{(\frac{2d}{(\delta\varepsilon)^2})}+\frac{4d}{(\delta\varepsilon)^2}\log{(2 \frac{e}{d})}\leq \frac{8d}{(\delta \varepsilon)^2}(1+\frac{1}{(\delta\varepsilon)^2})+\frac{4d}{(\delta\varepsilon)^2}a=(8+4a)d\frac{1}{(\delta\varepsilon)^2}+\frac{8d}{(\delta\varepsilon)^4}$

Now I want to say that $\frac{1}{(\delta\varepsilon)^{2}}\leq \frac{1}{\delta ^4}+\frac{1}{\varepsilon ^4}$ and $\frac{1}{(\delta\varepsilon)^{4}}\leq \frac{1}{\delta ^8}+\frac{1}{\varepsilon ^8}$ such that

$(8+4a)d\frac{1}{(\delta\varepsilon)^2}+\frac{8d}{(\delta\varepsilon)^4}\leq C(\frac{1}{\delta ^8}+\frac{1}{\varepsilon ^8}+\frac{1}{\delta ^4}+\frac{1}{\varepsilon ^4}):=p(\frac{1}{\varepsilon},\frac{1}{\delta})$

Is my polynomial fine?